Proof that the anticommutator of positive semidefinite operators is positive semidefinite
Let $A, B$ be positive semidefinite hermitian operators. Then, my (attempt on a) proof is as follows:
For any arbitrary density matrix $\rho$ in our Hilbert space,
$$\text{tr}[\{A,B\}\rho] = \text{tr}[AB\rho] + \text{tr}[BA\rho] \ge 2\lambda_{\text{min}}(A)\text{tr}[B\rho] \ge 0$$
Where the first inequality comes from here and the second one comes from the fact that $\lambda_{\text{min}}(A) \ge 0$ ($A$ is positive semidefinite) and $B$ is also positive semidefinite. However, I saw on other posts like this one that this is not generally true.
Am I missing anything here?

The inequality you quote  works for two selfadjoint operators. But there is no reason for $B\rho$ and $A\rho$ to be positive, and they often are not even selfadjoint, as the example you mentioned shows.

Following the answer in that post, there is no requirement mentioned about self-adjointness

Not sure what you mean. You say that the inequality holds for arbitrary operators?

@user3141592 In both posts that you have mentioned, it is clearly stated that the matrices are Hermitian (= self-adjoint).
